# Debian login on power up

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, sddm

How can I avoid this, and immediately boot into Lubuntu?

[image]

Comment: What DM are you using?   Lubuntu's default has been `sddm` for awhile; was your system a fresh Lubuntu (LXQt) install? or a *legacy* LXDE install upgraded (*where issues were expected as documented*).  There are packages in Ubuntu repositories that still mention Debian (those coming from upstream & not used by *flavors* like Lubuntu) so packages added to your system likely explain it, or *unsupported* upgrades.

Comment: @guiverc After the update, I got a black screen error. I reinstalled lxdm (didn't know what dm was) and now I get into tty. I press ctrl-alt-f7 and I get into the debian menu. Should I use sddm?

Comment: Lubuntu has used `sddm` as it's *display manager* since Lubuntu 18.10; as the *Simple Desktop Display Manager* is best suited for a LXQt/light desktop fitting the LXQt system.  LXDM is intended for LXDE which is now a Debian desktop *unsupported* by Lubuntu which has used LXQt in it's last eight releases (*not counting respins*).  Given you're using a Debian packaged `lxdm` on your system, why would the Debian background surprise you?  Lubuntu don't touch/support it; Ubuntu provides the upstream (Debian package).  What you use is your choice.  FYI: The DM provides *greeter* or login services..

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, I got it. sddm stopped working with the latest update, I tried again. I decided to put slim, and now everything is fine. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to right up your own answer then.  You can refer to me if I provided help, or just give details maybe on what change you made that caused your initial issue, plus what you did to resolve it. (FYI:  I didn't like `sddm` when Lubuntu started using it, but have decided I do love it)